# Remove Facebook auth to my website for my Facebook account

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to test the log-in flow for my website that uses Facebook auth.

Unfortunately, after the first time I log into my site with Facebook, I am never shown Facebook's auth window or flow again.  I' just automatically logged in.

How can I remove my permission to a particular website so I am presented with Facebook's login flow again?

Answer (score 0):

just remove your app from https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

afterwards it will ask for all permissions again.